# I wish "I had been born" or "I were born"

Tags: subjunctives

"Had been born" or "were born": Which one is correct in the following context?

"Australia is a very nice country. I have always wanted to visit Australia. I wish ***I had been/were born*** in Australia."

I think the past perfect tense is correct here. But I am not sure.

Comment: From the amusingly-titled [*If Wishes Were Hearses*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=A82oCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&lpg=PT4&dq=%22I+wish+he+were+dead%22+or+%22I+wish+he+was+dead%22&source=bl&ots=QYdY96F8bf&sig=25qpcbBf8EHIsIli8id4SAyO89E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiov_2IqJbXAhVFuhoKHdQtAlcQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22I%20wish%20he%20were%20dead%22%20or%20%22I%20wish%20he%20was%20dead%22&f=false): *'I wish he was dead', said Mr. George White ... 'Were', corrected his daughter patiently. 'I wish he **were** dead'*. But in casual speech (increasingly, I suspect) we don't bother with that "correct" subjunctive.

Comment: I agree with that, @FumbleFingers.  Still, the question here, as I understood it, was not about the *was/were* (or indicative/subjunctive) contrast, but the *were/had been* contrast.  Would you agree that for a past hypothetical, *had been* is used (*I wish I had been in France with you last year*, not *I wish I was/were*), or do you think that distinction is dying out as well?

Comment: @rjpond: The specific verb *[to be] **born*** somewhat complicates the issue. You could only *actually* have been born once, wherever it was, and the reference is to some other ***hypothetical/unreal*** past, so we're not really in the normal past perfect context of one thing having happened before another. Try replacing the inevitably "one-time-only, enduring" verb ***born*** with something potentially "repeatable, rescindable" such as ***married***, and you'll see that creates a whole new set of things to "analyse" (if indeed it's worth doing so).

Comment: Not to mention *I wish I had been satisfied with my marriage,* as opposed to *I wish I **were** satisfied with my marriage*.

Comment: Use "were" for counterfactual situations in the present time (past subjunctive) and "had been" for counterfactual situations in the past (past perfect subjunctive).

Answer (score 3):

When talking about when or where you were born, you use the simple past (*I was born*).  So to talk about where you wish you had been born, you need to use the past perfect.  In wishes, the past perfect represents an unreal past (whereas *were* would represent an unreal present or unreal future):

> I wish I **had been** born in Australia.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the past perfect subjunctive form "had been" here:

> "I wish I **had been** born in Australia."

The past perfect subjunctive is used to talk about situations in the past that are counterfactual.  For example, one would say, "I was born in the United States"; not, "I am born in the United States" *unless* one's birth **were** in the present and being spoken about generally. The first-person singular simple past indicative of "to be" in English is "I was", but its past perfect subjunctive form is "I had been".

> "I **was** born in Australia." (simple past indicative: I am indicating that this event actually happened in the past.)
>
> "I wish I **were** an Australian citizen." (past subjunctive: I am not
>   an Australian citizen right now in the present, but this is my wish.)
>
> "I wish I **had been** born in Australia." (past perfect subjunctive:
>   I was not born in Australia, but, presently, this is a wish of mine;
>   of course, it can never come true.)